# Spring Integration ExecutorChannel running on Same Caller Thread

Tags: spring-integration

Need to process messages sequentially, irrespective of the `spring.task.scheduling.pool.size` threads defined. Hence, we defined a `ExecutorChannel` with single thread. However, we see the messages are processed parallelly by the caller's thread. Please suggest how to process the messages sequentially **without blocking the caller thread**.

```
@Bean
public MessageChannel svcErrorChannel() {
   return new ExecutorChannel(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());
}

return IntegrationFlows.from(svcErrorChannel())                                             
                       .log(ERROR, m -> "ErrorFlow Initiated: " + m.getPayload())
```

**Application Logs:**

```
2023-02-04 20:21:03,407 [boundedElastic-1          ] ERROR o.s.i.h.LoggingHandler - 1c710133ada428f0 ErrorFlow Initiated: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2023-02-04 20:21:03,407 [boundedElastic-2          ] ERROR o.s.i.h.LoggingHandler - 1c710133ada428f0 ErrorFlow Initiated: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `log()` operator is essentially a `ChannelInterceptor` where that logging happens in a `preSend()` hook - the part of a `MessageChannel` on producer side. Therefore it is expected to see your Reactor threads in those logs.

If you really would like to log consumed (not produced) messages, then you need to use a `.handle(new LoggingHandler())` instead of `log()` operator. Or you can use a `.bridge()` before your `log()`.

See docs for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-log

Comment: Perfect, thanq. Is there any limitation on `ExecutorChannel` as only a single thread (in our case) processes the messages?

Comment: That's not a channel we should talk about, but rather provided `Executor`. See Javadocs for that `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`. Looks like a memory is your limit.